# ruby error in code : undefined method `to' for 43:Fixnum (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new at ruby and doing some tuts now I noted down some code from a tut, but I get an error:

```
ruby1.rb:9:in `<main>': undefined method `to' for 43:Fixnum (NoMethodError)
```

this is my code:

```
print "Enter a Value:"

first_num = gets.to_i

print "Enter another value:"

second_num = gets.to_i

puts first_num.to.s + " + " + second_num.to_s  + " = " +
(first_num + second_num).to_s
```

Comment: puts first_num.to.s should be puts first_num.to_s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change it like

```
puts first_num.to_s + " + " + second_num.to_s + " = " + (first_num + second_num).to_s
```

You had an error in there, instead of `to_s` you had used `to.s`

Comment: Thanks a lot that was it !

Answer (score 1):

Your first to.s should be to_s

try this

```
puts "#{first_num} + #{second_num}  =  #{first_num + second_num}"
```